# How to sort id in descending order in datatable without display the id?

Tags: datatable

I'm using this method currently. But the first column is the id column. I want to hide the id column in the table.

```
$('#booking-table').DataTable({
  "order":[[0,"desc"]]
});
```

Comment: Hi @Aniq, what do you want to do? In title you mentioned how to sort id, and in description, you mentioned hide id column.

Comment: @yash I wanted to sort the id by in descending order but at the same time, I wanted to hide it from display on the table. Is it possible ?